# Prawn - Place image in footer on each page

Tags: ruby, prawn

I have an image `image.jpg` that I want to place in a footer at the bottom left of every page. I am currently doing that, using Ruby 1.9.3 and the prawn gem to create a PDF, like so :

```
start_new_page
image "image.jpg", :at => [0,30]
```

There are two issues with this :

1) I am creating pages dynamically, and I need the image placed on all pages. Since I never know how many pages will be created, I don't know how to place an image on each page.

2) My tables within my PDF are being written on top of the logo, causing the logo to not be visible.

I found this code snippet in a sample:

```
number_pages "<page> in a total of <total>", { :start_count_at => 0, :page_filter => :all, :at => [bounds.right - 50, 0], :align => :right, :size => 14 }
```

This will place text on each page, dynamically just the way I want it to; however, it doesn't work with images.

How can I place an image on the bottom left of each page within my document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what exactly is the problem here?

this works fine for me:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('hello.pdf') do |pdf|
  pdf.text("Hello Prawn!")
  pdf.image "image.jpg", :at => [pdf.bounds.right - 100, 0], :align => :right
  pdf.number_pages "<page> in a total of <total>", :start_count_at => 0, :page_filter => :all, :at => [pdf.bounds.right - 100, 0], :align => :right, :size => 14
end
```

and for adding it to all pages you can do this:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('hello.pdf') do |pdf|
  pdf.text("Hello Prawn!")
  pdf.start_new_page
  pdf.text("Hello Prawn!")
  pdf.start_new_page
  pdf.text("Hello Prawn!")
  pdf.page_count.times do |i|
    pdf.go_to_page i
    pdf.image "image.jpg", :at => [pdf.bounds.right - 100, 0], :align => :right
  end
  pdf.number_pages "<page> in a total of <total>", :start_count_at => 0, :page_filter => :all, :at => [pdf.bounds.right - 100, 0], :align => :right, :size => 14
end
```

there might be better alternatives, but i never used prawn before.

Comment: The issue is that your `pdf.image` method doesn't have a `:page_filter => :all` parameter on it, and this method is not an option for `pdf.image`. I need to the image to be placed on every page.

Comment: That's creative, `.go_to_page` is a new one for me and will be helpful in other scenarios as well. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you not use **repeat**?

```
repeat(:all) do
 image "image.jpg", :at => [pdf.bounds.right - 100, 0], :align => :right
end
```

You can find more information in the Prawn manual (page 98).